# Server client to Browser client communication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser, websocket, faye

This is more of a conceptual understanding gap rather than technical one. I am new to web socket\messaging api's.
I ran a chat application using faye ruby server and everything works fine between two browsers.I want to send a message from a stand alone ruby client to a browser client which is sending messages to same server.  Is it possible to send a message from a client like the one below to a browser whose script is also given below ?
This is not related to the application I created, but I was trying to understand the use of WS client api. Or specifically put , can I send message from a server client to browser client ? I guess I am lacking the understanding of the word 'client' here.

I see the messages on the server console, but the browser doesn't get the message sent by the stand alone client.

Also I see this when i run the client :

Started GET "/faye/test123" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-09 07:17:46 -0400

```
require 'faye'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
    ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://localhost:9292/faye/test123')
            ws.onopen = lambda do |event|
        p [:open, ws.headers]
        ws.send('987654321')
    end

    ws.on :open do |event|
        p [:open]
        ws.send('123 123 123 123')
        p [:sent]
    end
}
```

Browser script :

```
window.client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');

client.subscribe('/test123', function(payload){
    if(payload.message)
    {
      console.log('I am in here 77777.......'+payload.message);
      return $("#incomingText").append(payload.message);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I think it might be useful to highlight the difference between websockets and faye.

Faye is a framework that supports a number of transports, websockets being just one of them. It can also do long polling for example. One of the benefits of Faye is that it can select the right transport that both the client and server understand. It also implements a simple pub/sub protocol on top of that transport, giving you a nice API to build off of.

Doing a pure websocket implementation is totally doable, but if you're going to go with Faye it's probably a good idea to use Faye's publish/subscribe API and not muck with Faye's websockets directly.

To answer your specific question:

> Is it possible to send a message from a client like the one below to a browser whose script is also given below ?

Yes, absolutely but I would suggest doing it with `Faye::Client`. Here's what your server side code might look like:

```
client = Faye::Client.new('http://localhost:9292/faye')

client.publish('/test123', 'message' => 'Hello world')
```

With much more info here:

http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/clients.html

Comment: It worked when I changed the protocol(it decided the protocol). But I am not able to understand why the server didnt pick it up or it didn't post to the other browser client with the Websocket server client . By the way you are right, i put http in browser code, when I put ws, it failed, No idea why !!!...I guess I got confused with the following example  : https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#running-your-socket-application